# claws-mail: can it compose mail beyond plain text?

Tags: linux, text-formatting, claws-mail

linux 6. claws-mail 4.

Claws 4 works well. But all emails are composed in plain, ascii text. No other formatting appears possible.

I want to know if claws supports the equivalent of rich-text: i.e. bold, bullets, numbered lists, colours, fonts, etc.

If yes, how to do?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used claws-mail for several years (until the Gmail OAuth switch) and I'm pretty sure it does not support composing non-plain-text emails.

Comment: Thanks for reply.